# Replacing bad file, directory and subdirectory names using a regex pattern

Tags: sed, command-line, regular-expression, mv

I have a bunch of directory, sub-directory, and filenames that were created in Linux with the following pattern: *YYYY* **-** *MM* **-** *DD* **T** *HH* **:** *MM* **:** *SS* (I added spaces for clarity but no spaces are in the directory/sub/file names; YYYY, MM, DD... are integers and '-', 'T', ':' are constants of the expression).

These directories/files were copied to Windows and then back to Linux, and the ':' got corrupted. Each place where there should be ':' there is '\357\200\242' which shows up as ??? when I do `ls`.

I know that fixing this should not be too complicated using a combination of `mv` and `sed`, but I'm very rusty on my piping, regex, and `sed` usage.

**So far I have this**

```
for a in *T*???*???*; do mv "$(echo "$a" | sed [***])"; done
```

The `[***]` should be a regex that changes `*T*???*???*` to `*T*:*:*` where the middle two `*` are each two digits. And this should rename both files and directories, recursively. I also suspect that `???` is not the correct input pattern to use here.

**Alternate approach**

I've seen a bunch of posts offering a combination of `find` and `rename`, but again, I am a bit rusty on the use of regex, and could not arrive at a good solution for this situation.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://regexr.com/) for regex, to test it, [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for sed , and come back with some updated work.

Comment: @jayooin, thanks for the regex tool. It came in really handy. Once I figure out how to put it all together with Ralf's answer I will put something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `\357\200\242` are octal numbers. Try:

```
rename -n 's/\o{357}\o{200}\o{242}/:/g' 2018-*
```

The command `rename` works with a Perl regular expression replace. Here it replaces three characters given as octal byte values with a colon.

Because of `-n` this just prints what it would do. So you are able to test without destroying something.

When you are sure that this does what you want, execute without `-n`.

If you need to traverse a entire directory tree, combine it with find:

```
find . -depth -exec rename -n 's/\o{357}\o{200}\o{242}/:/g' {} \;
```

Don't worry if the directory tree contains files that don't need to be renamed. If the regex replace does doesn't change the file name, the file is not renamed.

Comment: The regex seems to match the pattern correctly, but it is not looking inside sub-directories. However, I think I can take it from here and make it work.

Comment: @AOK See update

Comment: This worked perfectly. If I understand correctly, `find .` tells it to find everything, then `-depth` tell the command to go into sub-directories, and `-exec` tells it to execute the above `rename` for each thing found. Would it be faster to add the regex also to the find, instead of a `.`?

Comment: One other question: If the rename changes a folder name, does that affect the iteration through the folder/file list contained within the changed folder name? Thanks!

Comment: The dot `.` says: Start searching from the current directory. It is recursive by default. The `-depth` means process directory content before directory itself. This would be useful if also a directory name needed rename. If you want to restrict to certain file names, you would add something like `-name "2019-*"` (after `-depth`). The `find` command is very powerful and complex.

Comment: That last comment addresses everything, and indeed adding the `-name` option speeds things up significantly. Thank you.